# Как получить текст из комментария xml при помощи python

Tags: python

Есть xml файл. В конце этого файла есть комментарий
`<!--ND=10000000/010124/0000000-->`
Можно ли получить текст из этого комментария при помощи python? В частности нужно получить значение 10000000/010124/0000000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

xml_text = "<!--ND=10000000/010124/0000000-->"

pattern = r"<!--(.*?)-->"

comments = re.findall(pattern, xml_text, re.DOTALL)

for comment in comments:
    print(comment.strip())
```

`print()` выводит построчно элементы массива comments. Предварительно убираются пробелы в начале и конце via `strip()`.

**UPD** `print()` выводит строку "ND=10000000/010124/0000000"

Comment: Ну ваш код же выводит конкретный текст, я имел в виду этот текст, а не объяснение. Хотя оно тоже полезно ))

Answer (score 3):

Мне очень приглянулся bs4 для работы с xml.

Вот мое решение проблемы с получением текста комментария:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS, Comment

xml_text = "<!--ND=10000000/010124/0000000-->"
soup = BS(xml_text, 'lxml-xml')
comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
```

Так можно получить все комментарии в тексте. Рекомендую почитать документацию
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all